# SwiftUI onRecieve modifier triggers when a view re-renders

Tags: swift, swiftui, publisher

I'm trying to update input to a textfield using a Just publisher and a local state. Whenever the the view re-renders as result of a change to the local state the onRecieve modifier gets triggered. Here's a code sample to showcase the underlying issue.

```
struct MyTextField: View {
   @State private var someLocalState = ""
   @State private var inputText = ""

   var body: some View {
       TextField("Enter Text", text: $inputText)
           .onReceive(Just(inputText)) { newValue in
                print(newValue)
                // do something, store result in localstate
                someLocalState = doSomething() // this causes onRecieve to trigger and print again
                if someLocalState meets some condition {
                    inputText = someLocalState
                }
           }
   }
}
```

I always get an extra print. How do I prevent onRecieve from triggering when someLocalState updates

Comment: You need the local state to be the binding to the TextField, it's called single source of truth pattern which is crucial to SwiftUI's design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `onReceive` with `Just` to observe a `@State` value.

Instead, use `onChange(of:)`, which was designed for this purpose exactly - executing side effects when a non-published state changes.

```
struct MyTextField: View {
   @State private var someLocalState = ""
   @State private var inputText = ""

   var body: some View {
       TextField("Enter Text", text: $inputText)
           .onChange(of: inputText) { newValue in
                print(newValue)
                // do something, store result in localstate
                someLocalState = doSomething() // this causes onRecieve to trigger and print again
           }
   }
}
```

`onChange(of:)` is only available on iOS 14, so if you are targeting iOS 13, you can't use it unfortunately.

If you need a solution for iOS 13, you should check whether the value has actually changed and only execute the state update in case the value is different than the old value.

```
  .onChange(of: inputText) { newValue in
    print(newValue)
    guard newValue != inputText else { return }
    // do something, store result in localstate
    someLocalState = doSomething() // this causes onRecieve to trigger and print again
  }
```

Comment: I've updated the question. How would onChange work in this scenario with causing an infinite loop

Comment: @JobieJ because `onChange` only triggers when the value actually changes to a different value, so if the new value of `someLocalState` is the same as `inputText`, `onChange` won't trigger and hence the update loop is broken. I suppose if the new value of `inputText` is different than the old value, you do want to keep updating, right?

Comment: I had to create a new state to track oldValue. Then checked for changes. Thanks

Comment: they should just bind the TextField to the actual state and not create an extra one.